# Bug Using calc() On Table Cells in Safari 9

Tags: html, css, safari, html-table, calc

I can't find any information about this bug, but it looks like a pretty serious one.

When using `calc()` and mixing percentage and absolute values to set the width of a `<th>` in a table with `table-layout:fixed`, Safari 9 calculates the value as `-2px`. It works fine if all values are percentages or all values are pixels, but mixing the two always results in a result of between `-2px`.

Is there any workaround for this issue and is the issue documented anywhere?

```css
/* Table */

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0;
  -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  color: white;
}

th:first-child {
  /* width: calc(50%); works */
  /* width: calc(50% - 10%); works*/
  /* width: calc(400px - 100px); works*/
  width: calc(50% - 25px); /* calculates result of -2px */
  background: red;
}

th:last-child {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>First</th>
       <th>Last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QygXQB)